# I noticed a quick .crx download when starting Chrome - should I be worried?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

I just started up Chrome as usual, and just a few moments after it opened, the download bar at the bottom of the screen appeared, even though I didn't press anything. The file was a string of numbers and characters, and ended in a .crx extension (which I know is supposedly a Chrome extension). The download lasted less than a second.

Curious, I checked my Chrome download history to see what the file was. I then became suspicious, as there was no record of it downloading. I then checked my downloads folder on my file system - nothing there either. Worried, I performed a full scan with Microsoft Security Essentials, which told me that there were no threats on my system.

I run two extensions on Chrome: Adblock Plus, and an unpacked extension called YouTube Center.

So, my question is, should I be worried about this mysterious file? And if so, how do I deal with the threat?

Comment: When your :Security Essentials says **NO THREAT** I suppose that there is no need to worry. I downloaded chrome extensions myself and had this same worry. Chrome should somehow inform the user that this file was downloaded and should put a log for the user to see.

Comment: @Prasanna My worry was that I didn't download the extension myself, it downloaded on its own.

Comment: Very unlikely for that to get automatically downloaded. Let us say, it is a matter of concern - then - what do you intend to do now? You have already scanned ur PC for threats right?

Comment: @Prasanna Yes as I said, with MS security essentials. No threats were found.

Comment: Chrome might do that if you restored a crashed chrome session. Also what is YouTube center?

Comment: @sunk818 It's a legit extension, I've used it for a long time with no problems. Basically gives you a load more options for when you're watching youtube.

Comment: Have you signed into Chrome? If you have, then it could just be Chrome installing an extension you just installed on a different computer.

Comment: @ṧнʊß This is on my main computer. I've been signed in for a long time and installed my extensions ages ago

Comment: Well if you haven't installed any new extensions in any of your other computers recently, then I don't know why an extension was randomly installed, sorry

Comment: I also have youtube centre unpacked, as there's no other way to install it anymore. I too, observe the CRX file being downloaded at startup. It's probably because we are using unpacked extensions. Do you also get the dialog box asking to disable developer mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extensions can ([should](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/autoupdate)) update themselves, and as long as they do not need additional permissions, Chrome will be quiet about that. I don't know if such update would show as a download, nor if it would then show as a `.crx` download (I never noticed it). But you can check the file dates in the extension folder:

- Go to `chrome://version/`
- See the value for "Profile Path"
- On your file system, in that path, go into `/Extensions` and check the dates within the folders with the random names. (If you only use two extensions, I only expect 2 folders there.)

If you enable "Developer mode" in `chrome://extensions` then you can also see the ids that match those random names. On my Mac, Adblock Plus is at version 1.8.5, and that folder on my file system says it was updated September 8th. I don't use YouTube Center.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think it was probably an update, but it's always best to check

Answer (score 0):

This is strange, but I would not be too much worried about it.
Your antivirus is probably right, anyway, you should check all installed extension and disable what you don't want/need.

To ckeck and disable extensions just take a look here : https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/113907?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

I've looked into the same thing on my machine, and found it to be  related to Google Voice Search.

I followed Arjan's suggestion:

Go to chrome://version/
See the value for "Profile Path"
On your file system, in that path, go into /Extensions and check the dates within the folders with the random names. (If you only use two extensions, I only expect 2 folders there.)

there's a few new html files in there, and opening them in notepad I see talk of hotwords and google voice search, which I recall activating.

I'm satisfied that in my case, it's benign.